# PID controller convergence

Tags: convergence-divergence, control-theory

Is there any material anywhere on convergence of [PID controllers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PID_controller)? Ie, if we formalize the "plant process" in some way, like $y_{t+1} = f(x_t,y_t)$ (in other words, the process value at a given time depends on the previous process value and controlled value), are there conditions on $f$ that determine if there exist PID coefficients that converge, or on what the coefficients need to be?

I was experimenting with simulated PID controllers and found that it seemed very difficult to get a controller to converge for $f(x_t, y_t) = x_t^2$, and I was curious if the lack of dependence on the previous value ($y_t$) made the convergence difficult.

Answer (score 4):

In the linear case a PID closed loop is asymptotically stable (i.e. converges for $t \rightarrow \infty$) iff the real values of all eigenvalues of the closed-loop dynamic matrix are smaller than 0.

Explicitly speaking, in the single-input single-output case you have to compute the eigenvalues of
$$ 
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
A-(k_P+\frac{k_D}{T_f})\mathbf{b}\mathbf{c^T} & -k_I \mathbf{b} & -\frac{k_D}{T_f^2}\mathbf{b} \\
\mathbf{c}^T & 0 & 0 \\
\mathbf{c}^T & 0 & -\frac{1}{T_f}
\end{array}
\right],
$$
where $A$ is your (autonomous) system matrix, $\mathbf{b}$ is the input vector, $\mathbf{c}^T$ the output vector and $k_P, k_I, k_D, T_f$ the respective controller parameters.

In the nonlinear case that you're dealing with you can either try a linearization routine in the vicinity of a stationairy point and apply the condition given above. Alternatively, you could look for a Lyapunov function such that the energy of the system converges. These concepts usually require the autonomous system to be asymptotically stable, though, supporting your assumption that $f$ being independent of preceding states makes a stability analysis difficult.

In case you want to give it a try, here is the state space representation of the PID controller:
$$
\Sigma_{PID}
\left\{
\begin{align}
& \dot{\mathbf{x}} = 
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
0 & 0 \\
0 & -\frac{1}{T_f}
\end{array} 
\right] \mathbf{x} + 
\left[
\begin{array}{c}
1 \\
1
\end{array}
\right]e \\
& u = 
\left[
k_I, -\frac{k_D}{T_f^2}
\right] \mathbf{x} + 
\left(
k_P + \frac{k_D}{T_f}
\right)e
\end{align}
\right.,
\qquad \mathbf{x}(0) = \mathbf{x}_0,
 $$
where $e$ is the control error, $u$ is the control input and $\mathbf{x}$ are the states of the controller subsystem.

Note that one obvious trait of your system is that you will not be able to stabilize it for states $y_0 > y_c$, where $y_c$ is where you want to have it.

Good reads are: 
Hassan K. Khalil - [Nonlinear Systems](http://www.pearsonhighered.com/educator/product/Nonlinear-Systems/9780130673893.page) 
Alberto Isidori - [Nonlinear Control Systems](http://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540199168) 
Steven H. Strogartz - [Nonlinear Dynamics and Chaos](http://books.google.de/books/about/Nonlinear_Dynamics_and_Chaos.html?id=FIYHiBLWCJMC&redir_esc=y)

Comment: this looks like something that I'd like to check, could you please provide a direct reference to the proof of the derivation of the matrix in your answer? (i.e. page and book)

Answer (score 2):

The usual prerequisite for using PID controllers is that the plant itself must be stable in the first place. <s>The plant in your example is marginally stable, so you might want to consider stabilizing the plant (using pole-placement etc.) beforehand.</s>

Secondly, the selection of the coefficients of PID controllers are performed based mostly on heuristic methods as such the [Ziegler-Nichols method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ziegler%E2%80%93Nichols_method). The book [Modern Control Engineering](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0136156738) by Ogata has a whole chapter dedicated for introducing and discussing these methods.

---

Note that the methods presented assume a plant that can be adequately modeled by inhomogeneous linear ordinary differential equations of the form
\begin{equation}
 \sum_{i = 0}^{n} a_{i}(t)\frac{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}^{i}{y}}{\mathop{}\!\mathrm{d}{t}^{i}} = x(t).
\end{equation} 
Your example seems to suggest that you are dealing with a linear difference equation. So, you might want to consider a two-step approach, i.e. design an analog PID controller using the methods presented, and then digitize it.

Also, the input in your example is squared, $x_t^2$. When coupled with a PID controller, could result in a closed-loop system that is highly nonlinear in $y_t$, so your mileage may vary.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why $f$ is not stable? My interpretation of "stability" here is that the output of the plant process ($y_t$, in my notation) should remain stable if the input $x_t$ remains the same. $y_{t+1} = f(x_t,y_t) =  x_t^2$ satisfies this trivially as $y$ depends _only_ on the input. I would think something like $f(x_t,y_t) = y_t^2$ would be unstable. Am I not understanding stability?

Comment: Yes, your intuitive notion on stability is correct. However, I did not claim that the system is unstable; I stated that the system is [marginally stable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marginal_stability), i.e. it is neither asymptotically stable nor unstable.

But, I just realized that my comment on the stability of your plant is irrelevant because you are dealing with discrete-time system (in continuous-time domain, $\dot{y} = x^2(t)$, which looks similar to your plant and yet is completely different, is an integrator and marginally stable).

I will amend my answer accordingly.